# Windows 10 keyboard logging

Tags: c#, logging, keyboard, windows-10, keylogger

I've been messing around with hooking into windows using c# and logging all keyboard input, especially this being across users. I was wondering if it is actually possible to log all key strokes across User log-ins, not the actual sign in side (User/Pass) of the log in but if i locked the pc running the key logger and then logged into another account and typed something it would appear in the key-logger.

So far i haven't managed to get the key-logger to work across user accounts. However it does work fine logging the account that its run off. I've created an implementation based off : https://gist.github.com/Stasonix/3181083

This implementation works fine if i'm logged in on one account but not on another.

Can i just note this is purely for academic purposes. Is there a specific reason why switching users would cause it not to work?  I'm running this software on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Well, Windows separates processes per user. Unless you actually created a service that runs at the system level. it's impossible. By the way, do not attempt to create a windows service and use WinForms at the same time - it's not going to work

Comment: your application is running in [user mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode), so the data that it can operate on is severely restricted

Answer (score 0):

You could try by creating a Windows service instead of a console/winforms application.

Then change the run level (Log On As) of the service to local system and set the service to start at startup. This should work.